# .net core testing dbsets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit.net

I´m preparing my test infrastructure, but i´m facing some problems with my test repository.

The real repository access EntityFramework DbSet, like this:

```
public class Repository<T>: IRepository<T> where T : ModelBase
{
    protected ApplicationDbContext db;
    private DbSet<T> dbSet;
    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        dbSet = db.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(predicate).AsNoTracking();
    }

    ....
```

My TestRepository uses List instead of DbSets:

```
public class TestRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : ModelBase
{
    private readonly List<T> dbSet;
    protected ApplicationDbContextFake db;        

    public TestRepository(ApplicationDbContextFake db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.dbSet = db.Set<T>();
    }
```

This `db.Set<T>()` returns a List

The problem occurs when testing my code and there are something like this:

```
public async Task DeleteAsync()
{
    var items = repository.Where(....);
    repository.RemoveRange(await items.ToListAsync());
```

This code runs ok using Entity DbSets, but throws an exception when testing with my TestRepository:

> The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

Any suggestions to workaround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using EntityFramework Core (not EF6) - you may use in-memory implementation for your tests.

See docs for [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/) provider.

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a proper answer to why the error is happening, but I agree with the intent.

Comment: Perfect. As a bonus, I removed the TestRepository.